# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class when using jQuery to load partials

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a `dashboard_controller` where I'm attempting to allow a user to submit three forms for other controllers. I'm using jQuery to load the forms into a `div` when I click a link. The jQuery works fine and I can view the forms depending on the link I click. However, when I actually submit the form, I get an error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Here's the `dashboard_controller` action:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @message = Message.new
    @image = Image.new
    @link = Link.new
  end
end
```

Here's the jQuery I'm loading at the start to show my form:

```
$("#forms").html("#{j render :partial => "messages/form"}")
```

And here's the jQuery I have when a link is clicked:

```
$("#add_image").live('click', function(){
  $("#forms").html("#{j render :partial => "images/form"}")
})
```

And here's a link that I click, rendering a form:

```
=link_to 'Image', "#", :class => "btn btn-info btn-medium inactive", :id => "add_image"
```

Now if I click my `Image` tab, the image form is loaded. But when I click submit on that form, the error is thrown. Can anyone explain help me figure out how I can fix that?

**EDIT:** I have this working but it feels like a serious hack. In my other Controllers where there is a create action, I just assign a variable to a new Object. So for example if I am attempting to create a new message, the `create` action on `messages_controller` will look like:

```
def create
  @link = Link.new
  @image = Image.new
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  ...
end
```

Comment: What does the partial look like?